# Is there a way to speed up this query for million rows in both t1 and t1?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, database-cursor

Table t1 has primary key as NUMBER and we have to set the attributes A, B, C, ... using the rows of Table t2, hence using PIVOT.

This query is taking more than 4 hours to execute.

Is there a way to improve this?

```
DECLARE @number [varchar](40)

    DECLARE cursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT DISTINCT(t1.NUMBER) 
    FROM [TABLE1] t1
    INNER JOIN [TABLE2] t2
    ON t1.NUMBER = t2.NUMBER

    OPEN cursor

    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor INTO @number

    WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
        BEGIN
        UPDATE t1
        SET A = piv.A,
            B= piv.B,
            C= piv.C, ...
        FROM
            (SELECT A, B, C, ... 
            FROM
                (SELECT VALUE, NAME
                FROM t2
                WHERE NUMBER = @number
                ) d
                PIVOT
                (MAX(VALUE)
                FOR NAME IN (A, B, C, ...
                ) p
            ) AS piv
        WHERE t1.NUMBER = @number

    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor INTO @number
    END
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Comment: Getting rid of the `WHILE` would be a significant start. Why are you using one? SQL is a set based language, it can *easily* handle inserting 1 million+ rows in a single statement.

Comment: Why does this need a *cursor*, there's nothing being done that can't be done as a single set-based update which would probably be an order of magnitude faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it the SQL way.

Update from a Pivot.

```
UPDATE t1
SET A = t2.A
  , B = t2.B
  , C = t2.C
FROM TABLE1 t1
JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
      SELECT [NUMBER], NAME, [VALUE]
      FROM TABLE2
      WHERE NAME IN ('A','B','C')
    ) Src
    PIVOT (
      MAX([VALUE])
      FOR NAME IN ([A],[B],[C]) 
    ) Pvt
) t2 ON t2.[NUMBER] = t1.[NUMBER]
```

**Before update**

> ```
> select * from TABLE1
> ```

| NUMBER | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| 2 | *null* | *null* | *null* |

**After update**

> ```
> select * from TABLE1
> ```

| NUMBER | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a one | be one | you see |
| 2 | a two is too | too be or | not to see |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1cbe939efcf5b63203d1dc6a9714b080)*